# Is it better to sell items or to just ship them?

Tags: stardew-valley

I keep seeing people differentiating between selling and shipping items. Do you get better or worse prices based on how you sell an item or is it just the difference between having money now or later?

Comment: One bonus to selling to Pierre, often the other town residents will talk about buying the cranberry or whatever you sold to him and how good/bad it was

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Items put in the shipping container and selling directly to stores will net the same profit, so there is no difference there ([Source](http://steamcommunity.com/app/413150/discussions/0/405692758714359069/)).

With the shipping container:

- You must wait a day for your money
- Adds to the 'items shipped' statistic in the stats screen
- No concern about when shops are open
- You can put artifacts you cannot sell in the shipping container for some profit ([Source](http://kotaku.com/tips-for-playing-stardew-valley-1762894608))
- There are three achievements for shipping items. One for shipping 1 of every item, one for 15 of every item, and one for shipping 300 of any single item ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/StardewValley/comments/47z8vq/when_selling_crops/)). These exclude artifacts. A full list of items needed for achievements can be found [here](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Shipping).

The opposites of these points are true with selling to shops.

Based on these differences, unless you need money the same day, there is no downside to simply using the shipping box.

Comment: There is one other difference, items sold directly to Pierre will sometimes appear in pierres shop at a higher price so you can buy them back from him. It's not a very useful mechanic in practice.

Answer (score -4):

Price bonusses are only applied to shipped items.
For example having the fishing level 5 skill "Fishing" (fish are worth 25% more) and selling a gold star puffer fish (value 375g), which sells for exactly 375g at Willy's store, but you get 375 x 1.25 = 468g (floored) after shipping.

Comment: This is simply not true.